# How to Install Python 3.2.2 on CentOS 6.5 amd64 Preserving Its Original Python Installation (2.6.6)?

Tags: centos, python3.2

How to install Python 3.2.2 on CentOS 6.5 AMD64 preserving its original Python installation (2.6.6)?

Comment: What have you tried? What issue are you having? There's too little information to go off of

Comment: Hi Canadian Luke! Thanks for your comment! The question is that! Very objective and specific! I can not imagine what more I can add... Below I answer what I ask! I hope that I have been helpful to this community that I so appreciate! =D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Install Python 3.2.2 (CentOS 6.5 AMD64):**

In order to compile Python you must first install the development tools and a few 
extra libs. The extra libs are not strictly needed to compile Python but without 
them your new Python interpreter will be quite useless

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools"
sudo yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel
```

Here are the commands to download, compile and install Python

```
cd /usr/local/src
sudo wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.2.2/Python-3.2.2.tar.xz --no-check-certificate
sudo tar xf Python-3.2.2.tar.xz
cd Python-3.2.2
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
sudo make && sudo make altinstall
```

After running the commands above your newly installed Python interpreter will 
be available as /usr/local/bin/python3.2

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.2
```

Download and install Setuptools + pip

```
cd /usr/local/src
sudo wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py
sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.2 ez_setup.py
sudo /usr/local/bin/easy_install-3.2 pip
```

Create your isolated Python 3.2 environment

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3.2 install virtualenv
sudo /usr/local/bin/virtualenv /usr/local/virtenv3.2
cd /usr/local/virtenv3.2
source bin/activate
python --version # (To check version)
```

Source: http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos

Comment: It worked perfectly with Python 3.4 by replacing "3.2" with "3.4" and the Python-3.2.2.tar.xz URL with the 3.4 URL :)